# JS .animate is resetting the element to the original position after it is done executing

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I´m spinning a circle till 180° after that animation the circle hops back to 0° from where it started.
I´m sure it is because I called it in an function which is triggered by an onclickevent and there is no state of the circle-object(`#XOWheel`) saved.(because I don´t know how to do that)

```
function showWhoIs() {
  console.log(main.stats.currentPlayerIdx); // 0 = O | 1 = X
  document.querySelector('#XOWheel').animate([
    { transform: 'rotate(0deg)' },
    { transform: 'rotate(180deg)' }
  ], {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1
  });
}
```

Is there a better way to do that what I did here?
And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set the `fill` property of the animation to a suitable value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming/fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How an animation behaves *after* it ended, can be specified using the `animation-fill-mode` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

And you can set this using the Web Animations API as well, via the `EffectTiming`  dictionary. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming/fill